# Swift 5 reflection get list of class properties and call them

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I have a class that uses class computed variables that may be accessed from both objc-c and swift. I would like to test all these properties that start with "const".

I have this:

```
import UIKit

class MyClass: NSObject {
    @objc class var  constMethod1 : UIColor {
    print("Method1")
    return UIColor.red
  }

  @objc class var  constMethod2 : UIColor {
    print("Method2")
    return UIColor.green
  }
}

var methodCount: UInt32 = 0
let methodList = class_copyMethodList(MyClass.self, &methodCount)

for i in 0..<Int(methodCount){
   let unwrapped = methodList?[i]
    // call method only if it starts with "const"
    let crtMethodStr = NSStringFromSelector(method_getName(unwrapped!))
   print(crtMethodStr)
    
    if crtMethodStr.hasPrefix("const") {
        // call it
    }
}
```

All I get is "init" in the return array? what is the problem? I saw on another thread that just adding "@objc" shoulld fix this.  Also how do I access one of these variables from the retuned array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418490-class_copymethodlist):

> Describes the instance methods implemented by a class.

`constMethod1` and `constMethod2` are computed *class* properties, which translates to *class* methods in Objective-C. So they won't be returned by `class_copyMethodList`. But fear not, the docs also say:

> To get the class methods of a class, use `class_copyMethodList(object_getClass(cls), &count)`.

So you can do:

```
let methodList = class_copyMethodList(object_getClass(MyClass.self), &methodCount)
```

To call it, you can use `perform`:

```
if crtMethodStr.hasPrefix("const") {
    let result = MyClass.perform(method_getName(unwrapped!))!.takeUnretainedValue()
    print(result)
}
```